# Why does opening multiple files from the file manager via "Open With Other Application" yeild different behavior than via return?

Tags: unity, 18.10, .desktop

### Context

I want to be able to easily open multiple selected files into (v)splits in Neovim-Qt from the file browser (as opposed to the default of opening into multiple windows).

I decided to make a separate "application" for the purpose, so I made a copy of the `nvim-qt.desktop` file (in `usr/share/applications`), and changed the Exec line from the default:

```
Exec=nvim-qt -- %F
```

to:

```
Exec=nvim-qt -- -O %F
```

(I also changed the filename, Name line and Comment line)

I then set my new application (which I named `Neovim-Qt-vs`) to be the default application for text files.

If there is a better way to do this, I would love to know, but that is not the focus of my question.

### My Current Issue

When I select multiple files and press the return key or click `Open With Neovim-Qt-vs` from the (r-click) context menu, multiple separate Neovim-Qt windows are opened (not what I want).

However, when I instead click `Open With Other Application` from the context menu, then choose `Neovim-Qt-vs` (the exact same application) and press return, I get a single window with the files each in their own split (my desired result).

My main question is: **Why do I get differing behavior from the two different (but logically similar) methods of opening?**

Thanks!